# Is there anyone hosting the "latest" knockout version on CDN

Tags: knockout.js, cdn

I can't seem to find a CDN version of the "latest" knockoutjs library, similar to this style
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

(I require this for automated testing , I realize the potential pitfalls of using the latest).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cdnjs appears to have the latest knockout version (3.0.0) : http://cdnjs.com/libraries/knockout/

Can't find an url that points to the latest ko version, like the jquery one. You could make one yourself. Just expose an url on a server somewhere that redirects to the latest ko version on the cdn. You'll just have to remember to update the redirect url from time to time...